# using AWS EC2 macOS for gitlab CI / CD

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, continuous-integration, gitlab

since AWS announced that they have now finally MacOS machines in their portfolio, and they are advertise it that was setup for customers to use it for their iOS CI / CD, I want to try that as well. Since I'm very new to the AWS ecosystem, I'm not really aware of what AWS provides overall which I could use for that.
I saw that they provide the macOS in a EC2 and also as a on demand service.

Status Quo:
I host my Repository in GitLab
I have a gitlab CI where I run the iOS pipeline through a curl in azure pipelines. (you pay for a agent per month and my experience with their stability is very bad)

What I want to achieve:
I host my Repository in GitLab
...
...
Run the iOS Pipeline on an AWS EC2 macOS instance on demand.

I already had a look into a lot of how to's but I always end up that I was not able to choose a macOS instance.

Comment: Log into the AWS Console, go to the EC2 service page, click launch instance, click launch instance from the dropdown, click select on the macos catalina or macos mojave, choose "mac1" as the only available instance type and continue with the configuration...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use AWS EC2 Mac but it is a bad choice. It requires a minimum allocation period of 24 hours at $1.083 per hour. With this price you have plenty of choices.

1. MacStadium.com - so far most stable cloud mac I have used. You have to setup runner by yourself, price begin from $59/mo.
2. [GitHub Actions Mac runner](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/specifications-for-github-hosted-runners) - Ease to use with all software pre-installed. Work best with GitHub repo, can also work with Gitlab with a little twist. Free for 200 minutes/mo.
3. [macOS Runners on GitLab.com](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/1830) - Work best with Gitlab but still in close beta. Price not decide yet. Use MacStadium under the hook.
4. bitrise / buildkite / buddybuild etc. all very good if you don't mind they take care of everything for you.